# Passing SoPlex parameters to SCIP

Tags: scip

I am using the SCIP solver in AMPL mode, with SoPlex as the LP solver. This is the pre-compiled version available at https://scipopt.org/index.php#download.

I am solving mixed integer programs (MIPs) and would like to tell SoPlex to use the dual simplex algorithm for the LP subproblems. To do this, should I just specify `lp/initalgorithm = d` and `lp/resolvealgorithm = d` in [scip.set](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php)? Or is there some way to send settings to the SoPlex subproblem solver, along the lines shown [here](https://soplex.zib.de/doc/html/PARSLIST.php)?

Comment: hi man, my answer to your JS arrow functions is here: https://github.com/silentmantra/arrow-functions/blob/master/README.md
wrote it but the answer was deleted unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Setting the parameters as you suggested is exactly correct. That guarantees that SoPlex will start with the dual simplex every time (which it would almost certainly also do by default).